# Uncompressed video chat solutions?

Tags: video-conferencing

I am looking for a video call tool capable of transmitting and receiving uncompressed or losslessly compressed video between two participants (or more, but even at SD that is a little ambitious, requiring >1 Gbps download speeds).

There was some discussion of similar projects in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3719438/), but since the paper is quite old, it seems that most are no longer maintained, impossible to find, incompatible with current systems, or require specialized hardware systems.

- Uncompressed SD video at, say, 640 by 480 would be ideal, since uncompressed HD video generally comes in over 1 Gbps. I have 3-4 to work with, but the other people would probably not have any better than gigabit upload and download speeds. 4K is right out, since it would require speeds in excess of 6 Gbps, but if there is a tool that supports it, it might still be useful to know for the future.
- Still, losslessly or very lightly compressed HD video chat tools are fine.
- Ideally, the tool should work with a regular discrete GPU and not require a separate video capture card to function, but that is not a deal-breaker. It should certainly not require any hardware besides a desktop computer, however provisioned.
- It should ideally not be extremely expensive for the class of application (video chat), since similar albeit lower-quality functionality is available at no cost. Say no more than $500 per year or for a perpetual license.

Does anyone know of any  applications or frameworks that fit this description?

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote "Does anyone know of any applications or **frameworks**", does this mean you can use APIs or libraries to write your own application?

If yes, you could use the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia Streaming SDK Libraries](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/streaming) to do this using the programming language of your choice such as C++ or C#. (Disclosure: I work for LEADTOOLS vendor).

The SDK has the ability to stream live video uncompressed (full frames) and can also use different video codecs. At least 3 LEADTOOLS video encoders support lossless compression, which are:

- LEAD Screen Capture Encoder: Always lossless, optimized for screen capture but can be used with any video.
- LEAD Motion JPEG: Has both lossy and lossess compression options.
- LEAD Motion JPEG200 (MJ2K): Has both lossy and lossess compression options.

The SDK can be used on any Widows PC and doesn’t require any specialized hardware. If you would like to try it, you can find a free evaluation [here](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/streaming#section-start-coding).

If you wish to see the C# demo for example, you can find its source code in this folder:
LEADTOOLS22\Examples\Multimedia\DirectShow\DotNet\VideoConferencingDemo

If you run the demo, go to the **Server Properties** section and in the **Control** tab set the **Pre-defined Settings** to **Custom** then change the **Video Compressor** to one of the four options. If you choose one of the 2 codecs that support lossy compression, you can change its settings to lossless by pressing the **Properties** button to show its settings dialog.

The options and dialog are shown in this image:

[image: Video compression options & settings]

Comment: Does it also do audio? Or would that have to be worked in with another SDK?

Comment: Also, I suppose I should have mentioned  that more than $1000 for a simple video chat application that I would have to develop myself is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify your need for distance versus realtime. For realtime communication an important factor is amount of delay, and mimum possible delay vary depending on the transfer medium.

I would recommend to look at one of [Voctomix](https://github.com/voc/voctomix) (rtp packets), or [DVswitch](https://web.archive.org/web/20180420174154/http://dvswitch.alioth.debian.org/wiki/) (DV frames over ethernet), or [Nageru](https://nageru.sesse.net/) (USB3 or PCI on single system).

All those tools are Free Software (a.k.a. Open Source) which means (among other things) that they are free-of-charge for your own use (and for redistribution as well, as long as you follow the license).

As I understand your question, you need two-way realtime audio-and-video *conferencing*. Neither of those tools are turn-key solutions for that use-case specifically, but all are optimized for very-near-realtime editing so should be good contenders for piecing together two setups in opposite directions.